# How can one determine one's OwnerUserId on SE?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, data-dump

In the archives of shelved Stack Exchange sites, the authors of a Q or A are identified by a field "OwnerUserId" in XML files.

How can one determine one's OwnerUserId? Is it unique across SE sites?

Is there another mechanism for recovering one's own Qs&As on an archived SE site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your (Owner)UserId is determined per site (it's not likely, but theoretically possible to be equal to your UserId on another site). On this site, yours is 169797; on Stack Overflow, it's 704972. You can either go to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts), and check the URLs of the links to the site-specific profiles, or go directly to the `/users/current` page of a site (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) and check which number appears in the URL in the address bar after being redirected.

If the site isn't active anymore, you can check the Users table in SEDE or in the XML and look for the user with AccountID 362010; that's your 'global' user ID, which should appear in the network profile link.

Comment: I was pretty sure I had participated in an SE shelved site (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business). So I'm puzzled that grepping for my AccountID returns nothing.

Comment: According to [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/startups/query/822876), it's 14504.

Comment: Intriguing. So the schema for the tables is exposed!?

Comment: @Calaf [yes, it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232).

Comment: Ah.. I see. But running a `grep OwnerUserId=\"14504\" *` on the XML archives (which brings up nothing) should be just as good as a SQL query for one's old posts, no?

Comment: I thought so. But [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/startups/query/822905/startup-posts-by-calaf) returns one post for you. I actually haven't used the data dumps myself, TBH. I just know they're structured the same way as SEDE.